# Android Proguard Can't Find Methods in android.app.Activity

Tags: android, proguard

I'm getting the following Proguard errors when generating a signed APK. I have **minifyEnabled** & **shrinkResources** set to **true**

```
can't find referenced method 'void onMultiWindowModeChanged(boolean)' in library class android.app.Activity
can't find referenced method 'boolean isInMultiWindowMode()' in library class android.app.Activity
```

I want to keep minifyEnabled shrinkResources for production.

What would I need to add to my proguard-rules to keep above members and get rid of the error?

Here's my lengthy Proguard Rules file:

```
#-dontobfuscate

#-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable
#-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/simplification/cast
#-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/simplification/cast


-optimizationpasses 5

-dontpreverify

#-allowaccessmodification

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-adaptresourcefilenames
-adaptresourcefilecontents
-flattenpackagehierarchy


-dontwarn org.jdom2.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.google.common.collect.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**


#-keep class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class android.widget.ProgressBar
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}


# ------------------------------------------
# Crashlytics
# ------------------------------------------
-keepattributes *Annotation*
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**


-dontwarn com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator


# ------------------------------------------
# RETROFIT config
# ------------------------------------------
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }


# ------------------------------------------
# FABRIC TWITTER config
# ------------------------------------------
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.**
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
#-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
#    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
#}


# ------------------------------------------
# OKIO config
# ------------------------------------------
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class okio.** { *; }



# ------------------------------------------
# InMobi config
# ------------------------------------------
-keep class android.app.Activity
-keep class android.app.Activity.**

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.inmobi.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient{
     public *;
}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info{
     public *;
}
# skip the Picasso library classes
-keep class com.squareup.picasso.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
# skip Moat classes
-keep class com.moat.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.moat.**
# skip AVID classes
-keep class com.integralads.avid.library.* {*;}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see `progaurd` rules?

Comment: Sure, just added to the description

Comment: Ok, I just found out what was wrong. Actually had nothing to do with Proguard. One of the libraries I'm using is referencing a newer version of AppCompat lib. I just marked it with -dontwarn as I'm sure those members will not be used in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I develop Android aar library and our client had the same problem, when he tried to apply proguard to his app with the connected library. In our case the problem was not related with AppCompat libraries. 
Our client had compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion (23), that is lower then in our library (25). Activity.isInMultiWindowMode() method, which we use in our library code, doesn't exist in Android API 23, which is a reason for the Proguard to generate a warning. As a result, I have added the following line to my library's .pro file:

```
-dontwarn android.app.Activity
```

@AlexVPerl did the same thing, but I think, that it is the responsibility of library author to prepare library for the case, when client app's compileSdkVersion is lower, than in library (at least by several units).